# Next.js application resources cannot be found when deployed in k8s

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I have a Next.js application, which is deployed in k8s. The page is visible, but it is not able to find js/css files. I have posted the error that I receive in browser console below.

[image]

Below is the docker file used.

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

I sh in to my pod and tried to see what files are there. I do see `.next` folder there .

[image]

Question, why is it looking under `_next` folder when Next.js creates `next` folder? How to fix this?

EDIT:
I also tried copying the .next contents in to _next folder. so now under my app I have both _next and .next. I still get the same error even though the path is valid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The files served at `/_next/static` are located in the `.next/static` folder on the file system. This is normal Next.js behavior and nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: any suggestion on why the application cannot find any thing under _next folder then? What can I check?

Comment: Do the missing files exist in .next/static? Did you try running a container locally?

Comment: Yes the files exist in .next/static inside the container. Yes locally it runs well.

Comment: On the Next-js side everything looks fine to me. The Dockerfile also looks the same as the official example. It might be an infrastructure-related problem.